# How to use the Kubernetes client-go server side apply functionality properly?

Tags: kubernetes, client-go

When I run the below code using client-go library I get an inscrutable error? What am I doing wrong?

```golang
    ctx := context.TODO()

    ns := applycorev1.NamespaceApplyConfiguration{
        ObjectMetaApplyConfiguration: &applymetav1.ObjectMetaApplyConfiguration{
            Name: to.StringPtr("foobar"),
        },
    }

    if _, err := kubeClient.CoreV1().Namespaces().Apply(ctx, &ns, v1.ApplyOptions{}); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

Yields the very unhelpful error:

`panic: PatchOptions.meta.k8s.io "" is invalid: fieldManager: Required value: is required for apply patch`

What is the correct way to send an Apply operation to the API server in Kube using client-go?

Answer (score 0):

At least you should add `FieldManager` in your `ApplyOptions` 
I am also trying this out, for now I am referring to https://ymmt2005.hatenablog.com/entry/2020/04/14/An_example_of_using_dynamic_client_of_k8s.io/client-go